# Split string on keyword (and) except when quoted ('... and ...')

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string like:

```
Price=10.00 and Count=30 and Name='a and b mix'
```

I want to get result:

```
["Price=10.00", "Count=30", "Name='a and b mix'"]
```

I use any way to get it but I can't. I need split them use 'and', but it should be ignore if 'and' is in the **quote**.

I try

```
("Price=10.00 and Count=30 and Name='a and b mix'" + ' and').match(/(.*?)and/g)
```

but get

```
["Price=10.00 and", " Count=30 and", " Name='a and", " b mix' and"]
```

Anybody know how to do that?

Comment: you want to regexp in javascript.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(.+?)(?:and(?=(?:[^']*'[^']*')*[^']*$)|$)
```

You can try this.See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/jI8lV7/5

The problem with your regex `(.*?)and`

1) was that it will capture till `and` without checking if it is between quotes.`(?=(?:[^']*'[^']*')*[^']*$)` puts that check to consider `and` only when it is not in betwwen quotes.

2)After the last element there is not `and` but it is end of string.So you need to capture till `and|$` to consider all matches.

Comment: great, use 3 part for match them. first: (.+?) , mid: ?:and(?=(?:[^']*'[^']*')*[^']*$) , and last: $

Comment: add a blank after 'and' will be perfect. (.+?)(?:and (?=(?:[^']*'[^']*')*[^']*$)|$)

Comment: It is matching the space when it isn't inside quotes. You should fix your RegExp.

Answer (score 2):

Your RegExp matches too much. Try this one:

```
/(?:^|\b)[a-z]+=(?:'[^']+'|[^ ]+)/gi
```

It works as you expect.

You can check it in action here: http://regex101.com/r/pP3cG2/1

How it works:

It will check if it is the begging of the string or if you have whitespaces before.
Then, it will match at least 1 char from the group `[a-z]`.
After, it will match the `=` char.
To finish, it will match the char `'`, then anything that isn't `'` and then will match the `'`, or it will match anything that isn't a space.

---

To accommodate the information that splitting using the word `and` is a requirement, I made this:

```
/(?:^| and )([a-z]+=(?:'[^']+'|[^ ]+))/gi
```

The way it works is **exactly** the same (except of having `\b` I have `and`).

It just has a capturing group to ensure it works as it must.

Even though it works without all those checks (`(?:^| and )?` can be removed **safely**) I made the changes the O.P. said.

Here is an updated link: http://regex101.com/r/uA2eL4/1

As a side note, it can handle inputs with 'incorrect' formats:

`Price=10.00 Count=30 and Name='a and b mix'` Would match `Price[...]` and `Name[...]`
`Price=10.00 and Count=30 Name='a and b mix'` Would match `Price[...]` and `Count[...]`
`Price=10.00 Count=30 Name='a and b mix'` (no `and`s) Would match only `Price[...]`
`Price and Count=30 Name='a and b mix'` (no value on a 'token') Would match only `Count[...]`...

And so on...

Comment: nice, it's worked. But I want to use 'and' to keyword to split them, thx. I think @vks answer is I want to.

Answer (score 1):

I would propose the following regex if you are trying to match those key, value pairs.

```
"Price=10.00 and Count=30 and Name='a and b mix'".match(/\S+=('[^']+'|\S+)/g)
// ["Price=10.00", "Count=30", "Name='a and b mix'"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Just split the input string according to `<space>and<space>`.

```
> "Price=10.00 and Count=30 and Name='a and b mix'".split(/\sand\s(?=(?:[^']*'[^']*')*[^']*$)/g)
[ 'Price=10.00',
  'Count=30',
  'Name=\'a and b mix\'' ]
```

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
var str = "Price=10.00 and Count=30 and Name='a and b mix'";
var res = str.replace("and ", ",");
```

or `.split()` method

Comment: It's not what I want. I don't wanna spilt 'a and b mix'.